# Is it possible to Trim all the values in a column in a single statement?

Tags: sql, t-sql, trim

I've a table in a (MS) SQL database which has an Id column (identity, int) and a Name column (varchar(250)).
However, the values in the name column contain (fairly random) leading and trailing spaces as I think they were cut and pasted from "something else" (no idea what!).

Is it possible in T-SQL to do the following:

```
update MyTable set Name = trim(name)
```

and have it update all the Name columns with the trimmed value?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

MS SQL does not have a trim function. You'll need to use rTrim and lTrim together.

```
update MyTable set Name = lTrim(rTrim(name))
```

Answer (score 10):

Try

```
update MyTable set Name = LTRIM(RTRIM((name))
```

Answer (score 7):

Well as of SQL Server 2017 (14.x) and later there is a TRIM() function, so;

```
UPDATE MyTable set Name = TRIM(name)
```

Will work fine. Or in my case I also want to null empty fields after trimming.

```
UPDATE MyTable set Name = NULLIF(TRIM(name), '')
```

Answer (score 3):

You could try this:

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET Name = LTRIM(RTRIM(Name))
```

Take a look [here](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/04/24/sql-server-trim-function-udf-trim/) to create a function inside your database to use it faster

Comment: Thanks @Bazza answer appeared first, but thank you for the extra info.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

`UPDATE [table] SET [column1] = REPLACE([column1],'i:0#.w|',' ')`

Comment: This one is the only helping on replacing a given character across all values in a column. Can't believe TRIM only works with fixed strings...

Answer (score 2):

In SQL Server there is only `RTRIM` and `LTRIM`, but you can use them both together:

```
update MyTable set Name = RTRIM(LTRIM((name))
```

Answer (score 0):

Not quite - there's no `TRIM()` function available, so you have to use `RTRIM()` and `LTRIM()` (right- and left-trim, respectively):

```
UPDATE MyTable set Name = rtrim(ltrim(name))
```

Answer (score 0):

check for isnull if you want the empty string returned for the null case

```
 UPDATE MyTable set Name = rtrim(ltrim(IsNull(name,'')))
```